# Reducing CPU overhead when doing URL rewrites in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I use global.asax application begin request method to do URL rewrites. I know this will work. My only concern is that if I have a website with thousands of URLs or patterns to compared it. Is there any tip to reduce CPU overhead and conserved resources of the system? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. The regular expression patterns you use should be optimized, static and compiled.
2. You could segregate the regular expressions into different applications so different subsets would be tried per request.